# Online Advertisement - CAPTCHA test including an advertisement (IBM) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, ibm, online-advertising, us20120246008

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON implementing a CAPTCHA test based on an advertisement** - This application from [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/us/en/) seeks to patent the idea of...Providing a CAPTCHA test which includes an advertisement and a question related to the advertisement and determining a reward for the user based on the response. 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help."

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 3/23/2011** that discusses:

> - CAPTCHA tests which include questions on advertisements

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - Questions are selected based on **demographic information** associated with a user or a **random number**

**TITLE: Determining rewards based on CAPTCHA test**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] Receiving a request to access content from a user, providing a **CAPTCHA test** which includes an advertisement and a question related to the advertisement based on the **user response**, receiving a response to the question appearing in the provided **CAPTCHA test**, and determining a reward for the user based on the response and the **reward level** associated with the provided CAPTCHA.

- **Publication Number**: [US 20120246008 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120246008)
- **Application Number**: US 13/070,065
- **Assignee**: IBM
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 3/23/2011
- **Open for Challenge at USPTO:** Open through 3/26/2013
- **Link to Google Prior Art Search** - ["Find Prior Art"](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20120246008#c=0&d1=03%2F23%2F2011)

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A computer-implemented method for implementing CAPTCHA tests, comprising:
>
> 1. Receiving, using at least one computing device, a request to access content from a user;
> 2. Providing, using the at least one computing device, a CAPTCHA test to the user in response to the request, the CAPTCHA test comprising an advertisement and a question related to the advertisement, wherein the providing comprises:
>
>    2a. determining a demographic to which the user belongs, wherein the demographic is a measure of a level of potential familiarity with subject matter of the CAPTCHA test,
>
>    2b. determining a current affiliation level of the user, wherein an affiliation level comprises a measure of a level of access to the content allowed for the user,
>
>    2c. selecting a random number,
>
>    2d. determining whether the random number is even or odd,
>
>    2e. if the random number is even, fetching all CAPTCHA tests having an associated reward level that matches a next affiliation level as compared to the current affiliation level, remove therefrom any CAPTCHA tests not matching the demographic to yield a first remaining set of CAPTCHA tests, and providing a CAPTCHA test having a lowest impression count of the first remaining set of CAPTCHA tests, and
>
>    2f. if the random number is odd, fetching all CAPTCHA tests having an associated reward level that matches the current affiliation level, remove therefrom all CAPTCHA tests matching the demographic to yield a second remaining set of CAPTCHA tests, and providing a CAPTCHA test having a lowest impression count of the second remaining set of CAPTCHA tests;
> 3. receiving, using the at least one computing device, a response to the question appearing in the provided CAPTCHA test;
> 4. Determining a reward for the user based on the response and the reward level
>      associated with the provided CAPTCHA."

In English this means:

> A method for implementing CAPTCHA tests, comprising:
>
> 1. Receiving a request from a user to access content;
> 2. Providing a CAPTCHA test to the user in response to the request, the CAPTCHA test includes an advertisement and a question related to the advertisement, the providing a CAPTCHA test comprises:
>
>    2a. Determining a demographic to which the user belongs,
>
>    2b. Determining a current affiliation level of the user,
>
>    2c. Selecting a random number,
>
>    2d. Determining whether the random number is even or odd,
>
>    2e. If the random number is even, fetching all CAPTCHA tests having an associated reward level that matches a next affiliation level as compared to the current affiliation level, remove therefrom any CAPTCHA tests not matching the demographic to yield a first remaining set of CAPTCHA tests, and providing a CAPTCHA test having a lowest impression count of the first remaining set of CAPTCHA tests, and
>
>    2f. If the random number is odd, fetching all CAPTCHA tests having an associated reward level that matches the current affiliation level, remove therefrom all CAPTCHA tests matching the demographic to yield a second remaining set of CAPTCHA tests, and providing a CAPTCHA test having a lowest impression count of the second remaining set of CAPTCHA tests;
> 3. Receiving a response to the question appearing in the provided CAPTCHA test;
> 4. Determining a reward for the user based on the response and the reward level
>      associated with the provided CAPTCHA."

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 3/23/2011

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming Granting a level of access to the content for the user based on an elapsed time for the user to input the response

---

**"Offering rewards based on CAPTCHA test related to advertisements" from the Applicant**

[image]

**"Offering rewards based on CAPTCHA test related to advertisements" from the Applicant**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Answer (score 5):

The idea of advertisements as CAPTCHAs is not new. For example, Solve Media [filed a patent for this in 2010](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2011053967A1?cl=en&dq=solve+media&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Zy0iU7_4IKmR0QHLoIHICA&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAQ). However, I am not sure whether they have the additional complexity of customizing the ads for each user and using ads to give rewards, but given that Solve Media existed a long time before the IBM patent, that seems pretty obvious.

[Screenshots of their clients' advertisements](http://solvemedia.com/client-showcase)

[Solve Media on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solve_Media)